# LDDP vs info-entropy on binary float representations?

Tags: entropy, information-theory

I was just reading about [LDDP (Limiting Density of Discrete Points)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_density_of_discrete_points), and I see that it approximates a continuous distribution with an arbitrarily dense discrete distribution. And this reminded me of how we approximate floats with binary.

Then it occurred to me that as long as we limit our discussion to practical scenarios (i.e. numerical computations on a computer) then we can actually compute the original definition of information entropy by simply converting (e.g. 32 bit) floats to bit strings. **And I was wonder what would be the pros & cons of doing this vs using LDDP which also approximates continous distributions with discrete ones.**